# Function spl_autoload_call strange behaviour

Tags: php, autoload

Have this simple code that works on my localhost.

```
function autoLoaderFunction($classname){
    $file = path_to_server_document_root.'classes/'.strtolower($classname).'.php';

      if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && !class_exists($classname, false)){
          require_once($file);
      }else{
          throw new Exception('Class cannot be found ( ' . $classname . ' )');
      }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoLoaderFunction');
```

I have a problem when uploading it to the server. All paths are ok. but i have a lot of exception errors. This autoload function seems to try to load all files, not only classes, but functions, file names etc. Have errors like: 
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Class cannot be found ( language_id )" - where language_id is a url GET parameter.
and also like:
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Class cannot be found ( function_display_tempalte) where function_display_tempalte is a function name...
When i remove the throw new Exception line, the whole website is workign fine on the server, so this autoload seems to load all  neccessary classes properly, but also many other files that are not classes
Completely dont know what is going on here.
any advice? really appreciate !

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code is trying to instatiate an object of `language_id`. There is no other explanation for that behaviour. I would check the stacktraces of the `Exception` thrown in your autoload function.

Maybe the following solution is a good starting too:

```
if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && !class_exists($classname, false)){
    require_once($file);
}else{
    if($classname === 'language_id') {
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }
    throw new Exception('Class cannot be found ( ' . $classname . ' )');
}
```

However, a debugger can make your life easier, once you set it up.

Comment: it is giving houndres of exceptions. when i've added your code i have for example:  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(50) "application_top.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(114)
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(48) "main_func.php"
    }
    ["function"]=>
    string(7) "require"
  }  . So it means that this autoload function fires also when im using this line of code : require('main_func.php'); in the application_top.php file